# SQL: Correct Way to Grab First Row of a Group

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm migrating a site to Google's Cloud SQL service, which has an odd default with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, which means a common pattern that I use suddenly breaks down.

Consider the following:

```
SELECT `p`.`id`, `p`.`name`, `s`.`name` AS `latest_purchase`, `s`.`price` AS `latest_purchase_price`
FROM `Person` p
JOIN `Sales` s ON `s`.`person` = `p`.`ID`
GROUP BY `p`.`id`
ORDER BY `p`.`time` DESC
```

What I want is to get a list of results where each row is a unique person, with columns indicating the name and price of their most recent purchase.

The partial grouping behaviour I'm used to in MySQL is great for this, because it groups only on the person ID, and since my results are ordered the first row of each group is the one that I want, so I get the results that I expect.

But this isn't allowed with the SQL mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` which requires that all selected items are either in the `GROUP BY` clause, or use aggregate functions to select a single result.

Neither of these works in the above example, because adding everything to the `GROUP BY` means I would get multiple results per person, while using aggregate functions could give an inaccurate result, as the sale price isn't necessarily the highest or lowest in the group (I could potentially end up with a sale name and price, neither of which is the latest).

Fortunately SQL mode is one of the settings Google SQL allows a user to change, so I've just done that for the time being (edit the instance and go to set flags).

However if I were to use another system in future where I can't group as I wish, then what is the "correct" way to do this when partial grouping isn't allowed?

I realise there are some similar questions on StackOverflow already, but none that I've found quite captures my problem (as they involve much simpler examples where aggregate functions can be used).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is *filtering* not *aggregation*:

```
SELECT `p`.`id`, `p`.`name`, `s`.`name` AS `latest_purchase`, `s`.`price` AS `latest_purchase_price`
FROM `Person` p JOIN
     `Sales` s
     ON `s`.`person` = `p`.`ID`
WHERE s.time = (SELECT MAX(s2.time) FROM sales s2 WHERE s2.person = s.person)
ORDER BY `p`.`time` DESC
```

Comment: Sorry, the group by ordering was just a typo while creating a simpler example, I've corrected that in the original post, if you remove the reference to that in the answer I'll accept it.